# How to run a different roscore in different robots?

Tags: ros, multiple, roscore, machines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have two robots and I want to run a roscore for each one of the robots. But, I also need to exchange pose information between the robots. Therefore, there are topics from robot 1 that I need to publish on the robot 2 and topics from the robot 2 that I wanto to subscribe from the robot 1 (and the contrary).

There are any solution for that? Can anyone help me?

Many thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79211/how-to-run-a-different-roscore-in-different-robots?/) by [MiguelRobPinto](https://answers.ros.org/users/2036/miguelrobpinto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-09-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

You will want to run a single roscore that both robots use. The instructions on running ROS multiple machines should be a good place to start looking into this: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

It is very easy to do once you can get an ssh connection between the robots.

Hope that helps

Henry

---

Originally posted by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) with karma: 140 on 2013-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0